# Variables of extended class (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm trying to extend a class with the variables in the constructor. Here a little example.

I have my index.php with the following code in it.

```
<?php

namespace System;

require_once 'App/Config.php';

spl_autoload_register(function($class) use ($config) {
  require_once $config['app']['root'] . '/' . $class . '.php';
});

$app = new App($config);
$app->Start();

?>
```

All is working fine. Now I in the constructor of the class `App` passed the config file.

```
<?php

namespace System;
use System\Librarys\Database;

class App
{
  protected $config;
  protected $connection;

  public function __construct($config)
  {
    $this->config     = $config;
    $this->connection = $this->getConnection();
  }

  public function getConnection()
  {
    $this->connection = new Database;
    $this->connection = $this->connection->Connect();

    return $this->connection;
  }

  public function Start()
  {
    echo 'test';
  }

  public function __destruct()
  {
    $this->config     = null;
    $this->connection = null;
  }
}

?>
```

Ok, all good! But now, I want to make the database connection. I extended the "App" class in the database class. Like below:

```
<?php

namespace System\Librarys;
use System\App;

class Database extends App
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct(??? HOW DO I GET THE VARIABLE FROM THE "APP" CLASS ???);

    var_dump($this->config);
  }
}

?>
```

And now, if I do a `var_dump()` on `$this->config` it returns `null`. That's clear because I didn't pass the `$config var` in the parent constructor. But how do I do that? I want to set all variables in the `App` class so I can extend it, and don't need to pass the variables to the other classes.

Comment: You need to pass it into the `Database` class.

Comment: What im trying is to set all variables in the App class and then access it in the database class through the extended "App" class.

Comment: That's not how extending works.

Comment: BTW, plural _Library_ is _Libraries_

Comment: Ok, thats a detail. But how shoud i do that? is there a way to access the variables whitout passing it in every single class? i know static variables but thats not good practice they sad.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you just doesn't use the same constructor on `Database` class.
The code would be like this:

```
public function __construct($config)
{
   parent::__construct($config);
}
```

And then in `App` class

```
$this->connection = new Database($this->config);
```

By the way, if you're not going to add any more code to the `Database` constructor, you don't actually need it.

P.S.
I see in your code bad class design. You're probably using the `App` class for *global* configuration and the database connection is a part of it. So you need to create a single class that would handle all database operations. Then you just use it in your `App`'s instance. For instance:

```
class DB {
    function connect() { /* Some code */ }
    // More functions
}

class App {
    protected $db;
    // contructorts etc
    function run() {
        $this->db = new DB(/* some config */);
        // use it
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know this, but you know i have very much classes and passing the variables through every single class is hard, i mean is there a simple way to  do that whitout static variables?

Comment: see the edited answer. If you have a lot of classes and you have to pass some var throughout the whole structure — you have bad class design.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `__construct()` on `Database`, you can't get `$this->config` from `App` because it's not set yet.

You have to set the variable in the constructor before you can use it.

```
class Database extends App
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("localhost");
        var_dump($this->config); // $this->config is now "localhost"
    }
}
```